# Current YTD vs Last Month YTD Power BI Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Goal:**

- 1 - show the change of every month compare with last YTD in the table
  form in only selected year
- 2 - show the change in scorecard

**Data :**

```
ind YEAR    MON Figures
1   2020    JAN 12321
2   2020    FEB 344
3   2020    MAR 5000
4   2020    APR 325
5   2020    MAY 747
1   2019    JAN 54091
2   2019    FEB 349
3   2019    MAR 789
4   2019    APR 901
5   2019    MAY 2356
```

**Desire Result:**

- YTD column is accumulating Figures within the year
- Change column is showing
  the change compare to last month YTD

Usage - Default filter as newest year = 2020 , user can select the specific single year to view the change in scorecard

```
ind YEAR    MON Figures YTD     Change
1   2020    JAN 12321   12321   0
2   2020    FEB 344     12665   344
3   2020    MAR 5000    17665   5000
4   2020    APR 325     17990   325
5   2020    MAY 747     18737   747
1   2019    JAN 54091   54091   0
2   2019    FEB 349     54440   349
3   2019    MAR 789     55229   789
4   2019    APR 901     56130   901
5   2019    MAY 2356    58486   2356
```

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have relationship to calendar? Or in your table is column for MonthNo?
if yes then te simplest way to calculate YTD:

```
YTD = CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Figures] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Calendar'[Year], 'Calendar'[MonthNo] ),
            'Calendar'[Year] = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Year] )
                && 'Calendar'[MonthNo] <= SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[MonthNo] )
        )
    )
```

Here we sum [Figures] column for the current year (from table context), from 1 month to X month (current for row).

```
YTD_LY = CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Figures] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Calendar'[Year], 'Calendar'[MonthNo] ),
            'Calendar'[Year] = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Year] ) -1 //add -1 here
                && 'Calendar'[MonthNo] <= SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[MonthNo] )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that . What is the common practice to add which can match your answer with the situation of my data ?

Comment: does your [ind] column reflect the sequence of months? If so, it can be used instead of [MonthNo]

Comment: yes, but usually encounter another problem that 1 - original MON column is whole number , cannot directly link to "Calendar Table". Which i have to arrange processing step in M 1- Duplicate YEAR -> 2 - change to TEXT -> 3 - Custom column concatenate　YEAR　& MONTH -> 4 - change to Date ..... very bad practice

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need aggregated results, and assuming that Ind column is sorted by month, restarting each year, like in the sample data, then you might consider to create two calculated columns. Here I assume the table's name is "Tab"

YTD that accumulates the Figures value for the year of the current column up to the current month included

```
YTD =
VAR CurrentYear = Tab[YEAR]
VAR CurrentIndex = Tab[ind]
RETURN
    SUMX(
        FILTER(
            Tab,
            Tab[Year] = CurrentYear
                && Tab[Ind] <= CurrentIndex
        ),
        Tab[Figures]
    )
```

and Change, that at the row level is Just Figures unless the month i January, where its value is 0

```
Change = 
IF( Tab[Ind] = 1, 0, Tab[Figures] )
```

Then you can use these column in a table with YEAR and MON columns to get the correct level of granularity.

If you just need the last value for the currently selected year, like to be used in a card, then you can implement a measure to get the Last Change

```
Last Change =
VAR LastYear =
    MAX( Tab[YEAR] )
VAR LastIndex =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX( Tab[Ind] ),
        Tab[YEAR] = LastYear
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        VALUES( Tab[Change] ),
        Tab[Year] = LastYear,
        Tab[ind] = LastIndex
    )
```

Comment: Very appreciate the answer but DAX cannot refer to the original table for column [YEAR] except measure, any basic step i missed ?

Comment: Tab[YEAR} is accessible when defining a calculated column in Tab table, since we have a row context. We would get an error if defining a measure, since when defining a measure no row context exists.

Comment: How to define Tab[YEAR] into calculated column ? I get error of the first line of YTD =
VAR CurrentYear = Tab[YEAR] .... <-- that YEAR 's error shows CANNOT find name 'YEAR'

Comment: If I understand your problem, you directly used my code without replacing the table name I invented, Tab, with the actual name of  your table. Also, please check that the name of the column containing the Year is YEAR, otherwise replace it too. I hope this helps